# Android resize image file size before uploading to ftp server

Tags: java, android, bitmap, upload, ftp

I am uploading an image file to my ftp server but I want to reduce the file size before uploading it to 100-200kb , I searched for an answer but I couldn't find one that can suit my code..

Here is my uploading code (Takes gallery selected image path and uploads it)

```
public void uploadingFilestoFtp() throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftpClient = null;

    try {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(host));

        if (ftpClient.login(username, password)) {

            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String Location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();


            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
            boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile("FileToSend.jpg", in);
            in.close();
            if (result)
                Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("count", "error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: look for an api that compresses the file. Then just send the compressed file. Option 2, make a custom compression method, but I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Code to resize an image file has been posted a hundred times on stackoverflow. So very strange that you cannot find such.

Comment: @greenapps really? because I searched for a code to resize image from directory and upload it to ftp server and couldn't find one.. maybe you can send me a link

Comment: As you can already upload an image file to an ftp server the onlty thing you need is code to resize an image file. So you googled for `android resize image` and didn't find anything?